# How to add a value in existing value in mongodb?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I had change the path of my uploaded images in nodejs.
Now i  want to change the address of existing images in mongodb.

```
for example 
now it's
 post/2020/06/img1231.jpg
 post/2020/06/img3541.jpg

what i need to add '/uploads/'
 /uploads/post/2020/06/img1231.jpg
 /uploads/post/2020/06/img3541.jpg
```

It will be a great help 
thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please go through all these links: [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [how to good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Considering, your collection looks like below:

```
[
  {
    path: "post/2020/06/img1231.jpg"
  },
  {
    path: "post/2020/06/img3541.jpg"
  }
]
```

Then the following query will be helpful:

```js
db.collection.update(
    {},
    [
      {
        $set: {
          path: {
            $concat: [
              "/uploads/",
              "$path"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    {
      multi: true
    }
)
```

Updated collection will be like:

```
[
    {
        "path" : "/uploads/post/2020/06/img1231.jpg"
    },
    {
        "path" : "/uploads/post/2020/06/img3541.jpg"
    }
]
```